# Script needed for SSH key copying to ESXi hosts

Tags: shell, ssh-keys, esxi

I am using the below shell script for Linux machines.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for ip in `cat /root/ip`; do
    #    ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $ip
    sshpass -p "test" ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $ip
done
```

But for an ESXi SSH key, the path is different.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@machineip  'cat >> /etc/ssh/keys-root/authorized_keys
```

How can I fix this ESXi script?

Comment: What is that single single quote before "cat"? Why aren't there two (or none)?

Comment: Just open a terminal in ESXI and you can poke around and find the correct path. It's just Linux under the hood with the pieces put in different places.